# There is an analytical function that satisfies the following conditions.

Tags: complex-analysis

There exists a function $f$ and an open set $U$ such that $f=u+iv$ is analytic on $U$ with

$a)$ $u=e^x$,

$b)$ $v=y^2$

**Try:**
I am trying with the $b$. And by the C.R equations we have that $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$, that is, $u_x=2y$ and $u_y=0$. So, we will have $u=2xy+h(y)$ and $u=p(x)$. So, equating, we are going to obtain that both $p$ and $h$ are really constant. That is to say, $u=2xy+c$ and $u=p$, but this would be absurd since we would have that $u$ would be a constant function but at the same time no, I don't know if that will be correct.

And for the $a)$ I have not yet obtained anything. Could someone tell me if the reasoning is correct and help with the $a)$, I don't think there is a function with the condition $a)$ either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these functions can exist.

On $b)$, you correctly noted that $v_y=0$.  But $v_y=2x+h'(y)$.  It follows that $u=0$.  Hence $v=0$, a contradiction.

Similarly,  if $u=e^x$, CR equations imply $v=ye^x+h(x)$.

And $0=u_y=-v_x=-ye^x-h'(x)$, so that $h'(x)=-ye^x\implies h(x)=-ye^x+c$, a contradiction.